# ¿Como obtener el nombre del sistema operativo que usa el cliente con ASP.Net MVC 4.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

Estoy tratando de obtener el nombre del sistema operativo que usa el cliente cuando esta usando mi aplicación web, hasta ahora solo he podido obtener el nombre del sistema operativo donde esta corriendo la aplicación.

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
        foreach (ManagementObject os in searcher.Get())
        {
            result = os["Caption"].ToString();
            break;
        }
```

Les agradezco sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podés probar con esto:

```
HttpBrowserCapabilities Navegador = Request.Browser;
string SistemaOperativo = Navegador.Platform;
```

Nota: HttpBrowserCapabilities pertenece al nombre de espacios de `System.Web`

Otra posibilidad es usar `Request.UserAgent`. Algo así:

```
string SistemaOperativo = Request.UserAgent
```

Como @zevane comentó, en el caso de esta última alternativa, es necesario trabajar la cadena resultante, que es del tipo

> User Agent :: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0b; Windows NT 6.1; .NET CLR 1.0.2914)

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta, ya lo intente, el resultado no es el esperado porque me devuelve **WinNT** cuando yo esperaba algo como esto **Windows 10** o **Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 2015 LTSB**, ¿alguna otra idea?

Comment: La segunda sugerencia igual?

Comment: Con UserAgent obtienes lo que pides, aunque tendrás que procesarlo un poco. Échale un ojo a esta respuesta (en inglés) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117851/get-the-clients-operating-systems-name

Comment: la segunda respuesta si me funciona, aunque tenga que procesarlo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @zevane claro, me olvidé de aclararlo en la respuesta. Buen punto.

Answer (score -1):

Podrías probar con

```
System.OperatingSystem osInfo = System.Environment.OSVersion;
```

Comment: Hola ya lo intente pero me regresa el nombre del sistema operativo donde se ejecuta la aplicación web, lo que me interesa es saber las versión del sistema operativo que usa el cliente.

Comment: Eso te devuelve el sistema operativo del servidor, no del cliente